# What's the best way to work with MapView on multiple workstations?

Tags: android, android-mapview, keystore

We are a team of three people working together. Right now it is hard to distribute work properly since the debug apiKey was generated on my machine. MapView stop working when running on my friends' Mac/PC. What's the best way to get around this? Should I just replace my friends' debug.keystore with mine and put the key on svn too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to different `debug.keystore` mapview is not working...

Either create new map-apikey or create new map-api key in your Mac/PC.